# How to add javascript ScrollSpy to this smooth scroll function (No-Library (pure JS))

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

please take a look at this code in DEMO1: https://jsfiddle.net/Nxja/h6swpj92/ .

```
! function(e, t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("smoothScroll", t(e)) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = t(e) : e.smoothScroll = t(e)
}(window || this, function(e) {
  "use strict";
  var t, n, o, r = {},
    a = !!document.querySelector && !!e.addEventListener,
    c = {
      speed: 500,
      easing: "easeInOutCubic",
      offset: 0,
      updateURL: !0,
      callbackBefore: function() {},
      callbackAfter: function() {}
    },
*
*
*
 etc!!......
```

There is a simple page with smooth scrolling effect "non-library (Pure JS)", but there is a problem that I really do not know how to add **SCROLLSPY** to change the MENU's TEXT color according to what the section is. :(

*Is there any simple solution to implement the **scrollspy** to the DEMO1 above?*

I really need your help guys, because the javascript function used in *DEMO1* is too hard for me :(  Could anyone show me how to do it? I can not use jQuery, Bootstrap, React, Angular etc..

I have another example DEMO2:► https://jsfiddle.net/Nxja/8wbc7hdp/ , where the scrollspy works fine, **but I need to make it work in my original DEMO1**.

```
function menuControl(e) {
  for (var t = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop, n = e.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]'), o = 0; o < n.length; o++) {
    var r = n[o],
      i = document.querySelector(r.getAttribute("href"));
    i.offsetTop <= t && i.offsetTop + i.clientHeight > t ? r.classList.add("active") : r.classList.remove("active")
  }
}

function scrollSpy(e, t, n) {
  animated(e, t, n), document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    menuControl(e)
  })
}
window.requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(e) {
  window.setTimeout(e, 1e3 / 60)
};
```

I will appreciate every help, thank you in advance. :( ♥